# How to separate or draw some independent legends in a linear plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have been struggling to visually separate the legends. My data only has time vs amount of different growth values, but I need to separate the Raw Data (colored lines) from the geometric mean (black smooth curve).

Growth curves A

[image]

Growth Curves B

[image]

I have "successfully" plotted them, but I either get a plot with the 'geometric mean' without it appearing in the legend, or all four curves in the same legend.

I would love to separate them, so that the three lines have the title "Fluorescence excitation at" title, and the geometric mean of these lines, just the name "60 mM Mean". The reason I want that data to be separated is because I will be creating other graphs that will compare the mean fluorescence excitation at different concentrations (60, 30, 15, so on).

Data: [Small file with the data frame (28 observations of 11 numerical variables)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J-Emu2j6pZyCxDgoYOqg3bR0bZHLY9Om/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code for A:

```
GraphChl60mM <- ggplot(data = Combined60mM, mapping = aes(Tiempo)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm"), method = "loess", alpha = 0.35) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm")) +

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm"), method = "loess", alpha = 0.35) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm")) +

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm"), method = "loess", alpha = 0.35) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm")) +

  #Geometric mean
  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.60.mM, colour= "60 mM"), method = "loess", alpha = 0.5) +
  #colour= "Black"
  theme_minimal() +
  #theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y = "Fluorescence intensity", x = "Time (days)", title = expression(paste("Growth curve of ", 
   italic("Chlorella vulgaris "), "UTEX 2714 at 60 mM"))) +
#  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(16,17,18,21), fill = c('gray', 'grey', 'gray', "gray")))) +
#  guides(color=guide_legend("Mean excitation at")) + 
    scale_color_manual(name =bquote(paste("Mean excitation at ", lambda)), 
                       values = c( "335 nm" = "blue", "440 nm" = "red", "480 nm" = "orange", "60 mM" = "black"),
                       labels = c("335 nm", "440 nm", "480 nm", "Geometric mean values")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 10000))
```

And the code for graph B

```
GraphChl60mM <- ggplot(data = Combined60mM, mapping = aes(Tiempo)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm"), method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm")) +

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm"), method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm")) +

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm"), method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm")) +

  #Promedio  
  geom_smooth(aes(y= df_Comparative_Chlorella$`Mean.60.mM`, colour= "30 mM"), color= "Black", method = "loess") +

  theme_minimal() +
  #theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y = "Fluorescence intensity", x = "Time (h)", title = expression(paste(italic("C. vulgaris "), "UTEX 2714 at 60 mM"))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 10000))
```

Answer (score 2):

For multiple series, always try to "tidy" your data. That means gathering the names into one column and the values into another.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

geom.mean <- function(x) exp(mean(log(x)))

select(Combined60mM, Tiempo, starts_with("Mean.Exc")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-Tiempo) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Tiempo, y=value, col=factor(name))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", alpha = 0.35) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(
    name =bquote(paste("Mean excitation at ", lambda)), 
    values = c("blue", "red", "orange"), 
    labels = c("335 nm", "440 nm", "480 nm")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 10000)) +
  stat_summary(aes(lwd="Geometric mean values"), fun=geom.mean, geom="line", col="black") +
  guides(col = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  labs(y = "Fluorescence intensity", x = "Time (days)", 
       title = expression(paste("Growth curve of ", italic("Chlorella vulgaris "), "UTEX 2714 at 60 mM")),
       size=NULL)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I understand the general idea of your code, but I don't understand the intrinsic grammar of ggplot2 nor these "%>%" things. I believe I will be finishing this paper and then looking for any plotting alternatives to ggplot2. I don't understand tidyr or dplyr, and I want to write code with the least amount of packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very skilled with `ggplot2` but your question drew my interest, so I tried a few things with your second code based on this [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-2/).

```r
ggplot(data = Combined60mM, mapping = aes(Tiempo)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm"), method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.335, colour= "335 nm")) +

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm"), method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.440, colour= "440 nm")) +

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm"), method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Mean.excitation.at.480, colour= "480 nm")) +


  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "Fluorescence intensity", x = "Time (h)", title = expression(paste(italic("C. vulgaris "), "UTEX 2714 at 60 mM"))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 10000)) +

  scale_color_hue(bquote(paste("Mean excitation at ", lambda))) + 

  geom_smooth(aes(y=Mean.60.mM, colour= "30 mM", fill="Geom. Mean"), colour="Black", method = "loess")+

  scale_fill_manual("Geometric mean values", values=rep(1,4), guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("Black"))))
```

This yields
[image]

Perhaps you can use this answer to proceed further your desired result.

Comment: Thank you deeply for taking the time to try it yourself. I like that you respected my base code and tried to edit it, instead of deploying code alternatives and new packages. I will be using your recomendations :)